# How to use function parameter: call specific getter

Tags: java

I have a Dog class with a name and a breed. I want to print either the dog's name or its breed depending on a method parameter passed to a printDog method. How do I do that?

```
class Dog  {
  private String name;
  private String breed;

  //constructor

  public String getName()  {
    return name;
  }

  public String getBreed()  {
    return breed;
  }
}
```

```
public void printDog(Dog dog, ?)  {
  System.out.println(dog.?);
}
```

```
Dog dog = new Dog("Buster", "Shepherd");
printDog(dog, dog::getName);
printDog(dog, dog::getBreed);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Function<Dog, String>`. This represents a function that takes a `Dog` and returns a `String`.

```
public void printDog(Dog dog, Function<Dog, String> propertySelector)  {
  System.out.println(propertySelector.apply(dog));
}
```

You can call this exactly the way you wanted:

```
Dog dog = new Dog("Buster", "Shepherd");
printDog(dog, dog::getName);
printDog(dog, dog::getBreed);
```